# Is there any named entity reconginition algorithm trained for the french language?

Tags: classification, nlp, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

I am trying to implement a utility for my mobile application to perform some actions based on user questions. I need an algorithm to extract named entities from a text string (French grammar). I have used `nltk`'s interface to Stanford's NER models but it works only for English (A subset of other languages is supported but i can't find French). I have also used `Polyglot` but it seems that it doesn't do the work very well (Maybe the models I am using are not very well trained). I don't know if there is any free REST API that can do NER for the French language or any other algorithm or even an already trained model for `nltk`/`Stanford NER`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a french model free and ready to use via the spaCy package!

[Here are the small amd medium sized models, that should be ready to go](https://spacy.io/models/fr).

Here is the basic summary of the dataset, shown at the spaCy website:

[image: french spacy model details]

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Spacy models for french NER. You can [re-train](https://spacy.io/usage/training) them to enhance the results.

On the other hand, Google offers an [api](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/) but it may get pretty expensive depending on the amount of text you will send.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the flair/ner-French https://huggingface.co/flair/ner-french

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/86288)